# What is the best way to fetch different data from different tables with no relation to the same view in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent, relationship

I just wondering is there any proper or better way to fetch multiple data from multiple tables to the view without any relationships or joins.

I usually fetch them one by one and pass the arrays to the view as shown in the codes below :

```
public function showProfile(){
    $kode_manager = Auth::user()->kode;

    $data = DB::table('manager_infos')->where('kode',$kode_manager)->get();
    $data1 = DB::table('manager_tbls')->where('kode',$kode_manager)->get();

    return view('Web/pages/Profil', compact('data','data1'));
}
```

yeah, I might use Join or Eloquent Relationships but what if the data is totally different from each other that can't be related and joined each other? I'm just wondering is that okay to use this method or are there any other methods that are simpler or better? Thank you!

Comment: Are the tables related or not? If they're not related you may as well fetch independently.

Comment: Note you probably mean `compact($data, $data1)` here, not the literal strings `'data'` and `'data1`'. Even better: `compact(DB:table(...), DB::table(...))` which presents well if opened up across multiple lines.

Comment: @tadman no they are not, but if there, for example, like, 5 or 10 different tables, is it okay to use that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the tables are related in some way you're sort of stuck fetching them all with individual queries.

In practice so long as these queries aren't too painful this is usually not a big deal.

If do you have one that's especially egregious you may want to defer that by not fetching it here, and instead loading it with AJAX on the front end to improve perceived performance. A little "Loading..." box and then some data a second or two later is better than the whole page stalling for a few seconds.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer!